# Copy Realm object without adding to database

Tags: objective-c, database, swift, realm

In my app the problem is that user can edit an object, but if user pressed "Cancel" I need to discard changes, if there any method to make local copy of realm object without adding it to RealmBase, or I should do all  the copies manually?

Comment: Just do not commit your changes as far I know

Comment: my object already in Realm, I can't do anything with object without write transaction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your model doesn't have references to any other models or collection of objects, you can use [this](https://realm.io/docs/objc/1.0.2/api/Classes/RLMObject.html#/c:objc(cs)RLMObject(im)initWithValue:) method to initialise new instance with values stored in Realm.